# How to give URL in cron job in Cpanel for laravel routes?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel, web-hosting

Well, I am new to Hosting, I read a lot about cron jobs, to add a cron job in cpanel you have to specify the time at what time to execute, we need to specify the file path, but the question here I have is how can I specify the path here, I have a controller where cron job code and other code is written.

How can I specify the filename here, I have particular routes like this

```
https://exampple.com/cron_execute
```

How can I mention that in Cpanel?

P.s I am not using laravel cron controller it is my own custom controller.

Comment: I can't understand this point "for laravel routes" but simple set your File path dictionary /home/name_folder/run.php

Comment: @MahmoudGad I cant understand what you say, you mean just specify the route file?

Comment: Would suggest you do create command instead of doing through URL.

Answer (score 1):

Set the following command syntax in the cPanel-> cronjob section

```
wget -O - https://www.your-domain.com/cron-path >/dev/null 2>&1
```

remember to configure time interval settings like min, hour, day, month, etc to run the cron.

Answer (score 0):

In Cron job you can't use URL in order to run some scripts.

You have to create a Artisan command (check this https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/commands and specify your laravel project version in the top right corner menu) and than in the cPanel you have to register that command like `cd /path/to/your/root/file/of/the/laravel/project/ && php artisan schedule:run` and this will run the `schedule:run` command that will take care of running your command when you have specified, for example with `daily()`, `schedule:run` will run your command each midnight

Answer (score 0):

In cpanel with the specific domain name you can do it this way

/usr/local/bin/ea-php99 /home2/accounname/https://exampple.com/cron_execute_file

[Cpanel Cron job Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlAPo.png)